# How to print fp in HTTPError?

Tags: python, urlopen

After seeing this error with my urlopen() function:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_urlopen.py", line 47, in <module>
    response = request.urlopen(req, data, context=ctx)
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 227, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 541, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 653, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 580, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 508, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 663, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400:
```

I wrote a catch exception, but fp is empty when I printed it out.  Any ideas?

```
try:
    response = request.urlopen(req, data, context=ctx)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print ("the exception is %s " % str(e.fp())
    print ("the exception is %s " % str(e.fp.readlines()))
    exit(0)
```

Output:

```
the exception is <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0xd1b9615640>
the exception is []
```

fp isn't empty in the HTTPError class

```
class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        print (str(fp)))
        print (fp.readlines())
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

Output:

```
"fp <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0xd1b9615640>
[b'{"code":"6006","reason":"Failed to update".....}']
```

Thanks.

Comment: This means that line.readlines() is empty and ergo, e.fp is an empty file.  What is ```fp```?  Please explain what you're doing.   What should you be getting?  I'm confused with how your error relates to your code.  Where is this ```raise HTTPError(...)``` coming from?

Comment: fp isn't empty, I will edit my question for more details.

Comment: @ewong Sorry my question was confusing, I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm dense; but a few items that might help you.

1. You have an errant `"` in your `print("str(fp))`.
   (Thanks to @CrazyChucky for pointing that out.  Was
   particularly stupid of me to miss that.  Made more
   sense without the `"`)
2. In your code:

```
class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        print (str(fp))
        print (fp.readlines())
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

I noticed you do a `print (fp.readlines())` and then raise the error.
After that `print (fp.readlines())`,  the filepointer will be at the
end of the file.  So any further `fp.readlines()` will return `[]`

I'd suggest the following:

```
class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        print (str(fp))
        print (fp.readlines())
        fp.seek(0)
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

After noticing that the OP got an error with the `fp.seek(0)`,
and noticing that fp is a `HTTPResponse` object,
I'm not sure it's even possible to do an analogous `seek()`
action as the internal `fp` of HTTPResponse is a socket file
which (iiuc), doesn't allow seeking.

With that said, and if someone smarter than me can correct me,
the options are:

1. Remove the `fp.readlines()` altogether as that will set
   the fp pointer to the end and you can't reset it.
2. Copy the fp.readlines() items to a new file object (BytesIO())
   and pass that to HTTPError.

i.e.

```
class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        print (str(fp))
        olddata = fp.readlines()
        new_fp = io.BytesIO(olddata)
        new_fp.seek(0)
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, new_fp)
```

A possible problem that I see is if HTTPError requires new_fp
to be a HTTPResponse object.  But since this is a RAISE
line, the script/program would stop (assuming here..).

This is what I believe will give you what you want, though I'm
doubtful it is 100% what you want.  I apologize.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  Fixed #1 typo.  For #2, I added the fp.seek(0) per your suggestion and I got this " File "/lib64/python/lib/urllib/request.py", line 666, in http_error_default
    fp.seek(0)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek"

Comment: From https://pl.python.org/docs/lib/base-handler-objects.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750932/io-unsupportedoperation-seek,  and your original post,   I thought it was a file object, but itisn't a file object.

Comment: thank you so much.  Looks like it isn't a file object, but what you said made a lot of sense, so I went back and took out the print (fp.readlines()) in class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler) and that works!